# Ubuntu one on Ubuntu studio 12.04?

Tags: 12.04, xfce, ubuntu-studio

I want to install ubuntu-one BUT any time i am trying there is no success! So, any help?
Ubuntu studio 12.04 uses XFCE and nautilus as file manager. SO where is the problem?

**Edit 1**: Well, if i install from terminal then when i start the ubuntu one it starts to install. So, the procedure continues and suddnly the windows closes and then if i try to open again ubuntu one nothing happens.

**Edit 2**: When I run ubuntuone-installer from terminal i have

```
gabriel@gabriel-Desktop:~$ Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/ubuntuone-control-panel-qt", line 29, in <module>
    from ubuntuone.controlpanel.gui.qt import main
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntuone-control-panel/ubuntuone/controlpanel/gui/__init__.py", line 26, in <module>
    from ubuntuone.controlpanel.backend import UBUNTUONE_LINK
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntuone-control-panel/ubuntuone/controlpanel/backend.py", line 27, in <module>
    from ubuntuone.platform.credentials import CredentialsManagementTool
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntuone-client/ubuntuone/platform/__init__.py", line 34, in <module>
    from ubuntu_sso.xdg_base_directory import xdg_home
ImportError: No module named xdg_base_directory
```

**Edit 3**:

```
gabriel@gabriel-Desktop:~$ ubuntuone-client
ubuntuone-client: command not found
```

this is what I get when I run ubuntuone-client or sudo ubuntuone-client

Answer (score 0):

First off, did you try using command line AND Synaptic AND Software center (if it exists under Ubuntu Studio)?

For command line, use : `sudo apt-get install ubuntuone-client`.

For Synaptic, enter `ubuntu one` in the search bar.

For Software center, search for `ubuntu one`.

With each method, **tell us whatever error message you get** if you get any.

EDIT : Seen your edit, try launching the Ubuntu One installation from terminal as `sudo` by typing `sudo ubuntuone-installer`. **Tell me how it goes.**

Thanks, mjchopperboy

Comment: Lokk at my new edit!

Comment: Did you try what I told you to try? How did it turn out?

Comment: Sorry got the wrong command. Edit again!

Answer (score 0):

I wrote the following guide a couple of days ago for someone using Mint 12, but the process will be the same.

### Installing Ubuntu One Manually

First make sure the system is fully updated.

Open a terminal and use the following command :

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntuone-installer
```

When that finishes use the following command to start the installer :

```
ubuntuone-installer
```

After installation completes, if Ubuntu One is not in the applications menu, open nautilus and go to :

```
/usr/share/applications
```

Find the 'Ubuntu One' entry and copy it to your desktop.

Then double click it to open Ubuntu One.

Comment: any further help?

Answer (score 0):

Open terminal and use the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntuone-installer
```

After that install the `ubuntuone-control-panel-qt` through terminal

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntuone-control-panel-qt
```

This might help you.